# Where is the bug in this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have this code and the part in /**/ has some bug... I can't find it... When I delete that part of the code it works fine.

[**Problem**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jzy8h/)

[**Solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/E23GP/)

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#cTop').toggle(
    function(){
        showC();
    },  
    function() {
        hideC();
    }
);

$('#textDownRight').click(function(){
    window.location = 'http://nitidus-consto.kilu.org';
    hideC();
});

    /* The buggy code starts here */
$('.menuCircle').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: 55%,
            height: 55%
        }, 250);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: 50%,
            height: 50%
        }, 250);
    });
    /*it ends here*/
});

function hideC(){
$('#c').animate({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    'margin-left': '-50px',
    'margin-top': '-50px'
    },500);
$('#cTop').animate({
    'backgroundColor': 'rgb(25,25,25)'
    }, 500);}

function showC(){
$('#c').animate({
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    'margin-left': '-100px',
    'margin-top': '-100px'
    },500);
$('#cTop').animate({
    'backgroundColor': 'rgb(50,50,50)'
    }, 500);}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one

http://jsfiddle.net/qHeMD/1/

you're missing quotes around values with percents

```
    $(this).animate({
        width: 55% ,
        height: 55%
    }, 250);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: 50%,
        height: 50%
    }, 250);
```

should be

```
    $(this).animate({
        width: '55 %' ,
        height: '55 %'
    }, 250);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '50 %',
        height: '50 %'
    }, 250);
```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't animate.. I think I'll just stick in CSS :hover function...If you can solve that just say it :)..I can't accept it in 9 minutes, so just wait :)

Comment: It does animate when you remove the space between number and %, but it's kinda weird...http://jsfiddle.net/qHeMD/

Comment: @DavidDebnar: yes, I knew it does when it has not spaces between % and number, but I thought it's something different. Will now edit my answer

Comment: The OP will have to also modify the position of the pie slice to get it to look correct.

Comment: @BNL So I have to make a different function for each slice? That's what I didn't wanted to do :(...

Comment: Yea, probably. I can't think of a better way.

Comment: You could give each slice an id/class and have an array with the adjustments and look them up in the function. Something could be done. If its only 4 slices, probably not a big deal for them to each have a function. If more, it would be worth researching.

Comment: @genesisφ ,BNL When I animate both width+height and left+top than it should work... But I have to make it different for each... Top left will have left -5%, top -5%, top right top -5% etc...

Comment: @DavidDebnar: nice. feel free to add it into my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try making the percentages strings, like this:

```
/* The buggy code starts here */
$('.menuCircle').hover(
    function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '55%',
        height: '55%'
    }, 250);
},
function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '50%',
        height: '50%'
    }, 250);
});
/*it ends here*/
});
```